# In Angular2, is there a way to add a control (or formControlName) to a formGroup after it's been created?

Tags: angular

As title I need to add a single input control, from a component to a formGroup belonged to another component.
Both these two component are inside a parent/container component.

Comment: You can create a new object from the one you already have that is the easiest.

Comment: I need the single input to became a part of that FormGroup.

Comment: `onsubmit = function(){formobject.formctrlobj.x = 'xx'; /*do your XHR request*/}`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at FormGroup class I found this method:

```
addControl(name: string, control: AbstractControl): void;
```

so problem sorted out.